# Copy files of different format with one copy activity ADF

Tags: format, copy, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure Data Factory and I am trying to solve a particular issue that I have when copying files from ftp to azure storage account.I have to copy files from source folder to target folder . The files in the source folder are of different format (csv, txt, xml), and when I execute the pipeline all files are copied with .txt extension.

I am not sure how I can copy the files and keep their original format

Any help?

Note: I think the problem is the output filename that I didn't specify in the output dataset, but when I specify it by setting filename as item().name it is the name of the folder that contains the files that is copied and not the files .. any solution for that ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. it's already empty yet it still adds the extention . txt, from what I understood when fileName is not specified for an output dataset , the name of the generated file is in the format Data._Guid_.txt , when I specify the filename in the ouput data set like this --> file : @item().name , it copies the folders name in the block blob instead of copying the files that are in the folder (the ones with dat and csv formats) . so I dont know what else to do .

Comment: What is given in **File extension** property in Sink? By default File extension will be ".txt", make it empty if its not and try again.

Comment: Is it working fine after specifying the output filename?

Comment: yes still not working, I'm working on copying multiple folders with their files, so when specifying the filename I put : file : @item().name , and what it does is that it copies the name of the folder instead of the files.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Get Metadata` activity to get a list of folders from the path and `Foreach` loop activity to loop through the folder and copy files to sink.

1. **Use binary dataset** for source and sink to copy files.
2. Use `Get Metadata` to get the list of folders. You can parameterize the path or hardcode it.

[image]

**Output of Get Metada activity:**

[image]

3. Connect the `Get Medata` activity to `Foreach` loop and pass the **childitems** to the items list.

   @activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems

[image]

4. Add `copy data` activity inside Foreach loop and add folder path dynamically by **concatenating source dataset path and current item of Foreach loop**.

   @concat(pipeline().parameters.folderpath, '/', item().name, '/')

[image]

5. **In Sink**, connect it to binary dataset.

[image]

6. When you run the pipeline you can see all the files copied from source to sink irrespective of the extensions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the binary format.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-binary.

> You can use Binary dataset in Copy activity, GetMetadata activity, or Delete activity. When using Binary dataset, ADF does not parse file content but treat it as-is.
>
> ...
>
> Below is an example of Binary dataset on Azure Blob Storage:
>
> ```json
> {
>    "name": "BinaryDataset",
>    "properties": {
>        "type": "Binary",
>        "linkedServiceName": {
>            "referenceName": "<Azure Blob Storage linked service name>",
>            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
>        },
>        "typeProperties": {
>            "location": {
>                "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
>                "container": "containername",
>                "folderPath": "folder/subfolder",
>            },
>            "compression": {
>                "type": "ZipDeflate"
>            }
>        }
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: Binary format doesnt work it returns this error : Binary copy does not support copying from folder to file. I've already used csv format, is there any way i can make it work with that ?

Comment: You can't use csv format if some of the files you're copying aren't csvs.  Can you specify the error you're seeing? It sounds like you might just need to specify a get metadata activity on your source folder and then copy the files to the new location in a for each loop.

Comment: That's exactly what I did and it works fine, my only problem is that  the name of the generated files is in the format Data._Guid_.txt instead of their original format (. csv and .dat)

Comment: use the output from the metadata activity to specify the file name in the sink of the copy activity dynamically

Comment: like this filename : @item().name ? I did but when debugging it copies the name of folders instead of the actual files. 
 the structure of my source files looks something like this :
folder1 
    file1.csv
    file2.csv
folder2
   file.dat
   file2.dat